# Coordinates-based segments in plotly map start from the center

Tags: r, plot, visualization, plotly

I have a dataframe with 4 coordinates for several observation: longitude from, latitude from, longitude to and latitude to.
I want to make segment that appear on the map as in plotly's airport example  https://plot.ly/r/lines-on-maps/

I tried to change the code so it fits my data frame. The segment does go through the coordinates, but it does not start at the first coordinates but at the center of the globe and I don't really understand why. I am not sure what I do wrong.

[the plot as it appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsIQT.png)

[image]

Here is the code:

```
 geo <- list(
      scope = 'Europe',
      projection = list(type = 'azimuthal equal area'),
      showland = TRUE,
      landcolor = toRGB("gray95"),
      countrycolor = toRGB("gray80")
    )

    plot_geo(locationmode = 'Europe', color = I("red")) %>%
      add_markers(
        data = transfer.path.full[1:10,], x = ~lon_o, y = ~lat_o, text = ~name, hoverinfo = "text", alpha = 0.5
      ) %>%
      add_segments(
        data = group_by(transfer.path.full[1:10,],id),
        x = ~lon_o, xend = ~lon_d,
        y = ~lat_o, yend = ~lat_d,
        alpha = 0.3, size = I(1), hoverinfo = "text"
      ) %>%
      layout( title = 'E T 2016',
        geo = geo, showlegend = FALSE, height=800
      )
```

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I posted this on plotly forum as well and apparently this is a known issue that they are working on resolving https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/963

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer to this on another question I asked previously.  You will have to use `split =~ some_id`  This is similar to using the `paths` function in Tableau.

```
geo <- list(
  scope = 'Europe',
  projection = list(type = 'azimuthal equal area'),
  showland = TRUE,
  landcolor = toRGB("gray95"),
  countrycolor = toRGB("gray80")
)

plot_geo(locationmode = 'Europe', color = I("red")) %>%
  add_markers(
    data = transfer.path.full[1:10,], x = ~lon_o, y = ~lat_o, text = ~name, hoverinfo = "text", alpha = 0.5
  ) %>%
  add_segments(
    data = group_by(transfer.path.full[1:10,],id),
    x = ~lon_o, xend = ~lon_d,
    y = ~lat_o, yend = ~lat_d,
    alpha = 0.3, size = I(1), split =~ some_id, hoverinfo = "text"
  ) %>%
  layout( title = 'E T 2016',
    geo = geo, showlegend = FALSE, height=800
  )
```

Additionally, you may have to add `color = I('blue')` to the same line to make them all the same color.  I haven't found a way to group them all in the same legend group though as you would with traces `legendgroup`, if you come across how to fix that let me know!